WPF DataGridComboBoxColumn getting
I have some problems with DataGridComboBoxColumn. The first issue is that I do not see "default" value after loading data grid and I have to select it manualy from list. But when I select value it's correctly saved in my log file. The second issue is when I want to display this data from saved log file.
In the Obersvable collection it's correctly parsed but in DataGridComboBoxColumn value is not shown.
Here is my approach (yes I know it's not correct...):
XAML:
                <DataGridComboBoxColumn x:Name="sCurrentStatus" Header="Current Status" 
                SelectedValueBinding="{Binding sCurrentStatus, Mode=TwoWay}"                   
                DisplayMemberPath="{Binding sCurrentStatus}" />
                </DataGrid.Columns>

code behind :
        sCurrentStatus.ItemsSource = viewModelProjectTestsDescribed.listOfStatuses;
        viewModelProjectTestsDescribed.createTestsDescribedLogFile();
        observableCollectionListOfProjectTests = new ObservableCollection<ViewModelProjectTestsDescribed>();
        observableCollectionListOfProjectTests = viewModelProjectTestsDescribed.readTestDescribedLogFile();
        dgProjectTests.ItemsSource = observableCollectionListOfProjectTests;

in the "dgProjectTests" after all all values are correctly set and shown in DataGrid except the "Current Status" one.
